# Zebra ZD421 browser print bluetooth pairing error

Tags: android, bluetooth, zebra-printers

Whenever I try to connect my android phone to Zebra ZD421 via bluetooth in Discovered Printers in 'Browser print' app, it says

"Unable to connect to the device. The device will still be set as the default, but the application cannot retrieve information about it"

Printing does not work.

Also, I am not able to connect manually by Manage Devices by adding bluetooth mac address. It fails with similar message.

I can only use Browser Print successfully when printer is connected to router via Ethernet.

Interestingly, my mobile can connect via bluetooth via zebra 'Printer Setup' app. It's only the 'Browser print' app that is causing problem.

Ultimately I want to print from my react app.
Is there any way other than using 'Browser print' as this app is not even on Play store?

> - Platform: Android 13
> - Printer: Zebra ZD421
> - Mode: Bluetooth

Comment: Searching on "Zebra ZD421 SDK" does bring up Zebra software tools page. And searching on "zebra zd421 react native sdk" brings up https://developer.zebra.com/blog/develop-react-native-printing-app-android-ios-link-os-sdk If you are following existing examples, linking to the sample project and showing any Android logcat output with errors may be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that your ZD421 printer may not have Bluetooth Classic. The Browser Print works with Bluetooth Classic, but not Bluetooth Low Energy. The Printer Setup app works with both Bluetooth Classic and Bluetooth Low Energy. You can use the Printer Setup app to check the Bluetooth capability and settings on your ZD421 printer, by clicking on Connectivity Settings -> Bluetooth -> Next -> Controller Mode. To work with the Browser Print, the Bluetooth Controller Mode needs to be set as the "Both" or "Classic".
[image]